# Parse PFAnonymousUtils logInWithBlock not returning completion block when no internet connection

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I use Parse SDK 1.6.2 in my app. I'm trying to create an anonymous user using:

```
[PFAnonymousUtils logInWithBlock:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
      NSLog(@"Anonymous login failed.");
    } else {
      NSLog(@"Anonymous user logged in.");
    }
}];
```

If there is internet everything works fine, the completion block gets called and one of the NSLogs will be called. HOWEVER if there is no internet, the completion block NEVER gets called, the debugger will break somewhere in the Parse library but not crash. The console outputs "+[PFObject parseClassName]: unrecognized selector sent to class" but doesn't crash and instead just never calls the completion block and continues running. I think a workaround would be to check internet connection first but wondering if I'm missing something. Hector Ramos are you out there?

Comment: @Hector Ramos are you out there?

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between users created by `[PFAnonymousUtils logInWithBlock...]` and `[PFUser enableAutomaticUser]`. If you need unconditionally created anonymous user (including "no internet" conditions), use the second method. You can read details here: http://blog.parse.com/2012/04/02/protect-user-data-with-new-parse-features/